# Correct usage of ReadAsMultipartAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an endpoint that returns multipart content consisting of a file and some JSON. For testing purposes I return a large file of 960 MB

On the client side, I call the endpoint and get the response:

`var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:5094/message/test");`

When I look at the memory usage of my client before and after this line, I see that it increases from a few MB to about 980 MB, which makes sense.

Next I step over this line:

`var multipartContent = await response.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();`

Now the memory usage increases to around 3 GB.

Why does it increase so much? I would expect 2 GB since the data is being copied. Ideally, I would like to work with the data directly from the response message instead of having to make another copy, but if that is not possible I would like to understand why it doubles in size when reading it as multipart.

Comment: What is encoding of file part of multipart?

Comment: The file is read as a stream and placed in a StreamContent, then I set `streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream")`